# Guacamole RDP won't connect

Tags: guacamole

I use Guacamole with RDP protocol to connect to client. This my configuration:

```xml
<connection name="RDP 20.125">
    <protocol>rdp</protocol>
    <param name="hostname">192.168.20.125</param>
    <param name="port">3389</param>
    <param name="username">root</param>
    <param name="password">rahasia2020</param>
</connection>
```

But this didn't work when I tried to connect to it.

This is the error message from Guacamole:

> The remote desktop server is currently unreachable, if the problem persists, please notify your system administrator, or check your system log.

This the `./configure` result:

> ```
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  guacamole-server version 1.3.0
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  
>     Library status:
>  
>       freerdp2 ............ yes
>       pango ............... yes
>       libavcodec .......... yes
>       libavformat.......... yes
>       libavutil ........... yes
>       libssh2 ............. yes
>       libssl .............. yes
>       libswscale .......... yes
>       libtelnet ........... yes
>       libVNCServer ........ no
>       libvorbis ........... yes
>       libpulse ............ yes
>       libwebsockets ....... yes
>       libwebp ............. yes
>       wsock32 ............. no
>  
>     Protocol support:
>  
>        Kubernetes .... yes
>        RDP ........... yes
>        SSH ........... yes
>        Telnet ........ yes
>        VNC ........... no
>  
>     Services / tools:
>  
>        guacd ...... yes
>        guacenc .... yes
>        guaclog .... yes
>  
>     FreeRDP plugins: /usr/lib64/freerdp2
>     Init scripts: no
>     Systemd units: no
>  
>  Type "make" to compile guacamole-server.
> ```

And on the client side I already set RDP on port 3389. This is the result of `netstat -tunlp | grep "rdp"` on the client:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13645/xrdp-sesman
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13646/xrdp
```

So what is the problem, is there something wrong?

Comment: Can you reach port 3389 on the RDP server from the machine where guacd is running? Please run "telnet 192.168.20.125 3389" on the guacd machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a similar Guacamole Connection and attempted to connect. It failed with the same error.

The "system log" in the error is the Guacamole daemon log. Check your log for the Guacamole daemon, `guacd`. Depending on your system, the log can in different places. On RHEL/Centos: `/var/log/messages`. On Ubuntu/Debian, try the daemon log: `/var/log/daemon.log`.

I'm using RHEL, so I'll search `/var/log/messages` for `guacd`, but only the last 30 lines:

```sh
sudo grep guacd /var/log/messages | tail -n 30
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[3899120]: User "@1b862d83-323f-400b-819d-d082dd459074" joined connection "$2676e198-8ffb-458d-b115-d4d3b387d4a4" (1 users now present)
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[3899120]: Loading keymap "base"
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[3899120]: Loading keymap "en-us-qwerty"
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[3899120]: Certificate validation failed
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[2103350]: guacd[3899120]: INFO:#011Certificate validation failed
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[3899120]: RDP server closed/refused connection: SSL/TLS connection failed (untrusted/self-signed certificate?)
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[2103350]: guacd[3899120]: INFO:#011RDP server closed/refused connection: SSL/TLS connection failed (untrusted/self-signed certificate?)
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[3899120]: User "@1b862d83-323f-400b-819d-d082dd459074" disconnected (0 users remain)
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[2103350]: guacd[3899120]: INFO:#011User "@1b862d83-323f-400b-819d-d082dd459074" disconnected (0 users remain)
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[2103350]: guacd[3899120]: INFO:#011Last user of connection "$2676e198-8ffb-458d-b115-d4d3b387d4a4" disconnected
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[3899120]: Last user of connection "$2676e198-8ffb-458d-b115-d4d3b387d4a4" disconnected
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[2103350]: Connection "$2676e198-8ffb-458d-b115-d4d3b387d4a4" removed.
Sep 10 15:45:16 guacd[2103350]: guacd[2103350]: INFO:#011Connection "$2676e198-8ffb-458d-b115-d4d3b387d4a4" removed.
```

RDP is expecting a valid certificate from the remote server, but my system is using a self-signed certificate, so the certificate validation failed. The easiest way around this is to **ignore server certificate** for the Guacamole Connection.

In your configuration file, add the **ignore-cert** parameter to the Connection (from the [Guacamole Manual for RDP](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#rdp)):

```xml
<param name="ignore-cert">true</param>
```

If you still experience issues, refer back to the log. You may also want to set the **security** parameter, as Guacamole is sometimes unable to detect the security method automatically.